# Vue js No aparece información

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Node, Express, Vue y Mongoo,
pasa que quiero mostrar los items de la base de datos pero no me los muestra. Le estoy dando un console.log y si están pasando la información, llevo mucho en esto y no encuentro el problema.

Este es mi displayitem

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="row p-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="d-inline">Items</h1>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'CreateItem' }" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2">
          Create Item
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div><br />

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Item Name</td>
          <td>Item Category</td>
          <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items">
          <td>{{ item._id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
          <td>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'DetailsItem', params: {id: item._id} }" class="btn btn-primary">
              View
            </router-link>


          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    name:'app',
    data(){
      return {
        TheItems:[]
      };
    },
    created: function (){
      var vm=this;
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/item').then(function(response){
        console.log(response);

      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

y este es mi detalle del item

```
   <template>
      <div>

        <div class="row p-4">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="d-inline">Details Items</h1>

          </div>
        </div><br />

        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>

              <td>Item Name</td>
              <td>Item Price</td>
              <td>Category</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in items">

              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ category.title }}</td>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default{
        name: 'item',
        data(){
          return {
            item:{}
          }
        },
        created(){
          var vm= this;
          let id = this.$route.params.id
          axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/item/${id}`).then(function(response){
            vm.item=response.data;
            console.log(vm.item);
          })
        }

      }

    </script>

Y mi App.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'DisplayItem' }" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png"/>
      </router-link>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'CreateItem' }" class="nav-link">
              Create
            </router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <transition name="fade">
          <router-view v-bind:students="TheItems"></router-view>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>

  body{
    background-color: purple;
  }
  .fade-enter-active .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s;
  }
  .fade-enter .fade-leave-active {
    transition: 0;
  }
</style>

<script>
  export default{
    name:'app',
    data(){
      return {
        TheItems:[]
      };
    },
    created: function (){
      var vm=this;
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/item').then(function(response){
        console.log(response);

      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Estoy muy perdida y no funciona, llevo mucho tiempo en esto y no logro dar con el chiste.
Agradecería la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu componente no tiene una propiedad `items` sino `TheItems`, por lo que debieras corregir para que quede:

```
 data() {
      return {
        items:[]
      };
 }
```

Y supongo que ya lo estás haciendo pero como en tu pregunta no lo pones explícitamente, tienes que reasignar a esa propiedad el contenido que te devuelve axios

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/item').then((response) => {
    this.items=response; 
})
```

O bien al estilo old school

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/item').then(function(response){
    vm.items = response;
})
```

Nota: no tengo como probarlo ahora pero pienso que axios te devuelve la respuesta dentro de un atributo `data` de modo que debieras usar `response.data` en vez de sólo `response`. Vas a tener que probar tú misma.